# Pyinstaller - How to hidden import moviepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller, moviepy

I want to convert my script to an .exe and have tried it with pyinstaller.
The problem is that moviepy is not imported.
I imported moviepy as `import moviepy.editor as me` (in script.py).

So i tried the hidden import.
The command was: `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=moviepy script.py`

output:

```
3601 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'moviepy'  
3601 ERROR: Hidden import 'moviepy' not found
```

Could someone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`hidden-imports`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports) will only add the module itself and not its dependencies. It seems that PyInstaller can't handle `moviepy` automatically, and it would lack some dependencies like `imageio-ffmpeg`, so you can use [`Tree`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes) class and add both `moviepy` and `imageio-ffmpeg` to final executable.

Your spec file should look like this: (Remember to edit the module path based on your Python directory)

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ...
)
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/moviepy", prefix='moviepy')
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/imageio_ffmpeg/", prefix='imageio_ffmpeg')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
...
```

Finally, generate your executable with:

```
pyinstaller script.spec
```